# How to increment data using two sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets: sheet 1 contains a list of orders in ascending order. Sheet 2 is supposed to extract the last order number in sheet 1 and increment it by one.

This is what I have come up with:

```
=INDEX($A:$B, 29,1)
```

but essentially this is what I need it to do:

```
=INDEX($A:$B,29++,1)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `=INDEX($A:$B, MAX($A:$B) + 1, 1)`?

Comment: Why do you INDEX over two columns? Are your order numbers spread out over two columns?

Comment: @teylyn This was my mistake, I only need to INDEX over column 1. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @Tom Something like this could work.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are in **ascending order**, you can directly use the `=MAX (number1, [number2], ...)` formula on the order column (I will assume that column `A` is your ID one):

```
=MAX($A:$A) +1
```

You can use this to implement a progressive increment by one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this helps a bit. Thank you.

Comment: @KK1037 You're welcome. If you found this helpful, please accept it, so others can benefit from it.